# unable to run aws-azure-login when installed using npm install aws-azure-login command

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, azure, npm, npm-install

when I run **npm install aws-azure-login**, package is successfully installed but when I try to access, it throws the error(**'aws-azure-login' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.**) is there anyway to install this package such that all users of the computer can use it.

Comment: Have you tried with `npm install -g aws-azure-login`?

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned, you should run `npm install -g aws-azure-login`. However, this would install the modules in C:\Users\your_user\AppData\Roaming\npm, which might not be in your PATH.
Add this to your PATH environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

Please use `npm install -g aws-azure-login` to install the module globally.